# Definir CMD como terminal padrão do VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Eu tenho usado o terminal no ***VSCode*** bastante esses últimos dias, porém toda vez que eu abro o terminal ele muda de ***CMD*** para o ***PowerShell***.
[image: Sempre está no PowerShell]
Queria saber se a uma forma de definir o ***CMD*** como **padrão**.

Pra ficar **sempre** assim:
[image: Quero que sempre abra no CMD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta clicar na setinha :

[image: Setinha no terminal]

Depois clicar em `Selecionar o Perfil Padrão`:

[image: Menu aberto]

E aí seleciona o CMD:

[image: Caixa de dialogo para escolher o perfil padrão]